# I can't save from dataframe to postgresql

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:3434@127.0.0.1/postgres')

temp = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame()

vehicleList = {"LX59ANR", "SN63NBK", "YY64GRU"}

for ids in vehicleList:
    r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Vehicle/' + ids + '/Arrivals')
    r = r.text
    temp = pd.read_json(r)

    temp['Type'] = ids

    df = pd.concat([df, temp], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    df.head(0).to_sql('tfl_bus', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)  # truncates the table
```

Hello. cannot save data from pandas(dataframe) to postgresql. only column names occurred.

[image]

I removed head(0) result like this
[image]

Comment: `.head(0)` returns 0 rows. Remove it or replace 0 with a significant integer.

Comment: ok I saw that SN63NBK have data ..but you are not parsing correctly..let me see

Comment: I added this line : df['timing'] = list(map(lambda x: json.dumps(x), df['timing'])) like below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work , I added this line : df['timing'] = list(map(lambda x: json.dumps(x), df['timing']))

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import psycopg2
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
import json

r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Vehicle/SN63NBK/Arrivals')
temp = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame()
r = r.text
temp = pd.read_json(r)
temp['Type'] = '1'
df = pd.concat([df, temp], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True) 
engine=sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:3434@127.0.0.1/postgres')
df['timing'] = list(map(lambda x: json.dumps(x), df['timing']))
df.to_sql('tfl_bus2', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.head(0)` needs to be replaced with just `df`.

The `head(0)` strips away the actual data leaving the columns...

Comment: I changed it, but unfortunately no data

Comment: @istanbul34 but are you sure that your df have data ?

Comment: ok the error is in the column timing which contains data like this:

    {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.PredictionTiming, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities', 'countdownServerAdjustment': '00:00:02.0372375', 'source': '2020-01-13T04:51:25.969Z', 'insert': '2020-01-14T00:32:21.261Z', 'read': '2020-01-14T00:32:23.278Z', 'sent': '2020-01-14T00:33:02Z', 'received': '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'}

Which is a dict which the DB doesn't like.

Either drop this column or identify which bit of the dict that you want and extract it

Comment: also you should move .to_sql outside the loop, its just needlessly deleting and reinserting at present